# .svg Image in MAUI Blazor

Tags: image, svg, maui-blazor

i am trying to set an image in to a razor page in MAUI Blazor.
In MAUI (only), there was the aproach, that you have a .svg image in the folder Resources/Images. MAUI then converts the .svg image in a .png image which you can use in the XAML file. like so:

[image]

Now i have the same picture in a MAUI **Blazor** app and i hoped that i can put my picture in the same way expect that i have to use the HTML style like so:

```html
    <img src="one_list2.png">
```

But this doesn't work at all. I tryed with or witout path, path with slashes, backslashes etc. nothing works.

Trying to put a .png image into the wwwroot folder works. But this isn't the goal. I found it very nice to put a svg image which is then converted into a png depending of its size. This way all pictures would be converted exactly in the perfect size you will need lossless.

Thanks

Comment: I wanted to solve the problem as it is foreseen in MAUI. But the problem with the new frameworks is that many things are not backwards compatible. But if I don't find anything, I will implement this solution as a workaround for sure. Thanks.
Note: I'm sorry, but i can't rate this answer as useful due to lack of rights. I am quite new here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Add the image to Resources\Raw and set it to MauiAsset compilation type

Second, Check the project file to avoid setting the image in the other folder.

In razor component HTML:

```
 <img src="@imageSource">
```

In the code part:

```
private string? imageSource;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using var stream = 
            await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("testimage.png");
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        byte[] result;
        using (var streamReader = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(streamReader);
            result = streamReader.ToArray();
        }
        imageSource = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
        imageSource = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageSource);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //error
    }

}
```

More information you can refer to [ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid static files.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#net-maui)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in an other forum:

- Add a new Folder in wwwroot p.e. "img"
  The HTML-Engine understands SVG. There's noting to konvert. HTML itself has also the SVG Tag.
- so just add an image like this:

```html
<img src="img/myImage.svg" />
```

For me this works well...